# MySQL Ordering by win chance (%)

Tags: mysql

My table contains information this way:

```
Player_ID | isWinner
```

where `PlayerID` is the ID of the player, and `isWinner` is a boolean (0 for lose, 1 for win).

Same `Player_ID` can be in multiple rows.

My goal is to make a query to get ALL the information from this table ordered by the players, from the highest win rate (%) to the lowest.

Data example:

```
(Player_ID | isWinner)
1 | 1
1 | 1
1 | 1
2 | 0
2 | 0
2 | 1
3 | 0
3 | 0
3 | 0
```

The query will order this data this way:

- 1 | 100% -- > player ID 1 has the highest win rate
- 2 | 33% -- > player ID 2 has the 2nd win rate
- 3 | 0% -- > player ID 3 has the lowest win rate

I probably have to group by `player_id` and somehow calculate the `SUM` of `isWinner` of each player, then divide it by the numebr of records.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is that really `330%` win rate for player 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`avg()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg) to find the average of total wins for each player, then multiple by 100 to give the percentage

```
select
    player_id as pid,
  avg(is_winner) * 100 as win_rate,
    (
        SELECT
            count(player_id)
        FROM
            `34617596`
        WHERE
            is_winner = 1
        AND player_id = pid
    ) AS total_wins
FROM
    `34617596`
group by pid
order by win_rate desc
```

**See fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/10f797/1

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This query will return the average for each player:

```
select player_id, avg(isWinner) as avg_is_winner
from players
group by player_id
```

then you can join your table with this subquery:

```
select players.*
from
  players inner join (
    select player_id, avg(isWinner) as avg_is_winner
    from players
    group by player_id
  ) c on players.player_id = c.player_id
order by
  avg_is_winner desc,
  isWinner desc
```

Please see a fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5174e/2).